# Skip List Explanation (Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ by Adam Drozdek)

Tags: c++, search, insert, skip-lists

Can someone please explain the `skipListSearch()` and `skipListInsert()` method? The code is from Adam Drozdek's book [Data Structures and Algorithms in C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1133608426). 
In this skiplist, inserting does not require list restructuring and nodes are generated so that the distribution of the nodes on different levels is kept adequate.

`maxLevel = 4`. For 15 elements, the required number of one-pointer
nodes is eight, two-pointer nodes is four, three-pointer nodes is two, and four-pointer nodes is one. Each time a node is inserted, a random number r between 1 and 15 is generated. If r < 9, then a node of level one is inserted. If r < 13, a second-level node is inserted. If r < 15, it is a third-level node. If r = 15, the node of level four
is generated and inserted.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int maxLevel = 4;

template<class T>
class SkipListNode{

public:
  SkipListNode(){}
  T key;
  SkipListNode **next;

};

template<class T>
class SkipList{

public:
  SkipList();
  bool isEmpty() const;
  void choosePowers();
  int chooseLevel();
  T* skipListSearch(const T&);
  void skipListInsert(const T&);

private:
  typedef SkipListNode<T> *nodePtr;
  nodePtr root[maxLevel];
  int powers[maxLevel];
};

template<class T>
SkipList<T>::SkipList(){
  for (int i = 0 ; i < maxLevel ; i++){
    root[i] = 0;
  }
}

template<class T>
bool SkipList<T>::isEmpty() const{
  return root[0] == 0;
}

template<class T>
void SkipList<T>::choosePowers(){
  powers[maxLevel - 1] = (2 << (maxLevel - 1)) - 1;         // 2^maxLevel - 1
  for (int i = maxLevel - 2, j = 0 ; i >= 0 ; i--, j++){
    powers[i] = powers[i + 1] - (2 << j);                   // 2^(j + 1)
  }
}

template<class T>
int SkipList<T>::chooseLevel(){
  int i , r = rand() % powers[maxLevel - 1] + 1;
  for ( i = 1 ; i < maxLevel ; i++)
      if (r < powers[i])
        return i - 1;
  return i - 1;
}

template<class T>
T* SkipList<T>::skipListSearch(const T& key){
  if (isEmpty()) return 0;
  nodePtr prev , curr;
  int lvl;
  for (lvl = maxLevel - 1 ; lvl >= 0 && !root[lvl]; lvl--);            // level
  prev = curr = root[lvl];
  while(true){
    if (key == curr->key)
      return &curr->key;
    else if (key < curr->key){
      if (lvl == 0)
        return 0;
      else if (curr == root[lvl])
        curr = root[--lvl];
      else curr = *(prev->next + --lvl);
    }
    else{
      prev = curr;
      if (*(curr->next + lvl) != 0)
          curr = *(curr->next + lvl);
      else{
        for (lvl--; lvl >= 0 && *(curr->next + lvl) == 0; lvl--);
        if (lvl >= 0)
          curr = *(curr->next + lvl);
        else return 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

template<class  T>
void    SkipList<T>::skipListInsert(const   T&  key){
  nodePtr curr[maxLevel] , prev[maxLevel] , newNode;
  int lvl , i;
  curr[maxLevel - 1] = root[maxLevel - 1];
  prev[maxLevel - 1] = 0;
  for (lvl = maxLevel - 1; lvl >= 0 ; lvl--){
    while (curr[lvl] && curr[lvl]->key < key){         // go to next
      prev[lvl] = curr[lvl];                          // if smaller
      curr[lvl] = *(curr[lvl]->next + lvl);
    }

    if (curr[lvl] && curr[lvl]->key == key)          // dont include
        return;                                      // duplicates
    if (lvl > 0)                                 // go one level down
        if (prev[lvl] == 0){                     // if not the lowest 
          curr[lvl - 1] = root[lvl - 1];         // level , using a link
          prev[lvl - 1] = 0;                  // either from the root
        }
        else{                                         // or from the predecessor  
          curr[lvl - 1] = *(prev[lvl]->next + lvl -1);
          prev[lvl - 1] = prev[lvl];
        }
  }

  lvl = chooseLevel();                          // generate randomly level for newNode
  newNode = new SkipListNode<T>;
  newNode->next = new nodePtr[sizeof(nodePtr) * (lvl -1)];
  newNode->key = key;
  for (i = 0 ; i <= lvl; i++){                    // initialize next fields of 
    *(newNode->next + i) = curr[i];                 // newNode and reset to newNode
    if (prev[i] == 0)                                // either fields of the root
        root[i] = newNode;                         // or next fields of newNode's 
    else *(prev[i]->next + i) = newNode;           // predecessors
  } 
}
```

Comment: The best way to understand what this code is going is stepping through line by line with the debugger. Just asking for a complete explanation without stating in particular, what you don't understand is too broad here.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.